# JavaScript RegEx Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created the following Regular Expression in C# to extract tokens from a string in the format {token}. I developed the regex in C# and confirmed that it works.

```
// c#
var regex = new Regex(
    "\\{ (?>[^{}]+| \\{ (?<number>) | \\} (?<-number>) )*(?(number)(?!))\\}",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled);

var matches = regex.Matches("blah {token1} blah blah  blah {token2} blah");
```

The variable `matches` ends up containing two matches - "{token1}" and "{token2}".

I need to execute this in JavaScript, but I get a Syntax error in the expression when I try to execute the following line...

```
// JavaScript
var regex = new RegExp("\\{ (?>[^{}]+| \\{ (?<number>) | \\} (?<-number>) )*(?(number)(?!))\\}");
```

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?
Am I trying to use RegEx features that are not supported in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match all occurences of "{something}" try:

```
\{[^\}]*\}
```

Or is there another condition that has to be met? like {token[0-9]}?

http://rubular.com/ can help with testing.

Comment: No additional requirement. That does actually seem to work for me. The following line gives me the matches I need...text.match(/\{[^\}]*\}/g); It seems I was horribly overcomplicating it. I really struggle with the regex stuff. I have huge respect for anyone who has got their heads round it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Independent subexpressions qualified with `(?> ... )` aren't supported in Javascript regular expressions. The `?` is actually evaluated as a quantifier.

Comment: This is browser-specific, some actually recognize a more or less extended kind of regular expression.

Comment: I figured it would be something like this. Thanks for the info. It sounds like it's back to the drawingboard.

Comment: Yes. Suppressing capturing using `(?: ... )` does work for example.

Answer (score 2):

The main point is that if you use C# (or Java) you use a string to write the regular expression. In such a string you need to escape all escaping characters again, which is why you need "\\{" to escape a "{". JavaScript however supports its own syntax of regular expression similar to Perl and PHP I think.

Comment: So there is more than one problem with this. Incorrectly escaping characters as well as using regex features that the engine doesn't support. I'm good!